# How to create a Enom component in Yii framework

Tags: php, yii, yii-extensions, yii-components, yii-modules

I am new to yii and i have to create a yii component for Enom api .I have followed this url [Enom application](https://github.com/comdexxsolutionsllc/MoondayFramework/tree/master/engine/enom) for refrence . It is in core php and i want to implement this in yii as component or module .I have done in this way

1. put the files [interface](https://github.com/comdexxsolutionsllc/MoondayFramework/blob/master/engine/enom/class.EnomInterface.php) and [class](https://github.com/comdexxsolutionsllc/MoondayFramework/blob/master/engine/enom/class.EnomService.php) in the yii component folder.
2. modify the class as mentioned here [yii custom component](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/747/write-use-a-custom-component-in-yii2-0/) . Now my class name is `EnomService` and interface name is `EnomInterface` 
   i have added these lines also in my class

   use Yii;
   use yii\base\Component;
   use yii\base\InvalidConfigException;
3. modified the `main.php` file in config folder:

   ```
   'import'=>array(
       'application.models.*',
       'application.components.*',
    ),

   'defaultController'=>'post',

   // application components
   'components'=>array(
       'user'=>array(
           // enable cookie-based authentication
           'allowAutoLogin'=>true,
       ),
       'mycomponent' => [

           'class' => 'app\components\EnomService',

           ],
   ```
4. calling in the controller in this way .

   ```
   public function actionEnom () 
   {
        echo "asdgsgsag";
        $enom = new EnomService('manoj_rudra', 'manoj@41@', false, true);
        $enom->debug = true;
        $result=   Yii::$app->EnomService->checkDomain('systurn', 'com', true);
        //$result = $enom->checkDomain('systurn', 'com', true);   // This enables domain spinner
        echo '<pre>';
        var_dump($result);
        echo '</pre>';
   }
   ```

But it is not working . I am not so much familiar with yii custom component . Please help me to create this .

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Yii or Yii2?

If it is Yii, then you could use plenty of other existing extensions to inspire yourself, for example this one: https://github.com/HeavyDots/yii-sms

As for Yii2 you could do something similar, look into already existing extensions for Yii2 on YiiFramework website and you can see how component classes are defined.

I would recommend:

1) Create a new directory inside "components" named "enom"

2) Place inside that directory all your enom files from https://github.com/comdexxsolutionsllc/MoondayFramework/tree/master/engine/enom

3) Create the component class called "Enom.php" inside the directory, something like this:

```
<?php

// include enom service class
require(dirname(__FILE__).'/class.EnomService.php'); 

namespace components\enom;
use Yii;

class Enom extends \yii\base\Component
{
    // define private property to store service
    private $service;

    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();

        // init the service
        $this->service=new EnomService('manoj_rudra', 'manoj@41@', false, true);
    }

    /**
      * @return     EnomService
      */
    public function getService() {
        return $this->service;
    }

}

?>
```

4) Then in the configuration properly define the component

```
'enom' => [

        'class' => 'app\components\enom\Enom',

        ],
```

5) And finally use it like this

```
Yii::$app->enom->getService()->checkDomain
```

As I said before, haven't used Yii2 yet so this might need tweaking but could point you on the right path.

Comment: showing the error Alias "app.components.enom" is invalid.